# When i click drawer navigation menu, sub page button click events not triggering

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have drawer navigation menu items. when i click menu goes to activity. but that activity button click events not trigered. without navigation page button click events works.

With Navigation page:
`LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout container;
container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container);`

without navigate page:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
```

startActivity(intent1);

without navigation page working fine..

Its navigated to another activity. that activity button click events are not trigered.

Comment: You must clear about your issue, because it is not understandable,

Comment: when i click menu item its navigated to sub activity. in sub activity have buttons save, update, etc, these buttons not trigger. this is my problem.

Comment: can you share subactivity xml and button click events.

Answer (score 0):

If i corrrectly understand what you say you can't navigate when you click on item.
Have you override this method :

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.item1 :
                //Intent for action one
                break;
            case R.id.item2 :
                //intent for action two
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
      //if you xant to close the drawer navigation
        this.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }
```

this method allow you to make action when you click on item from the menu.

Comment: No.. its navigated to sub activity. but that sub activity have button save, update, delete like this. this buttons not working.

Comment: you must show us the code of the activity. We need it to help you.